# Conditional on which remote_user is being used?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to have a conditional in a Role which checks the remote_user being used? Something like:

```
- block
  ....
  ....
when: <The remote_user being used to connect is 'bob'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You should be able to write a normal Ansible condition:

```
- when: ansible_user == 'bob'
  block:
    ...
```

This presumes that `ansible_user` contains the value you care about.